# User input is not promted in CentOS7 using systemctl or service command

Tags: linux, shell, service, user-input, centos7

Am trying to stop the system service using systemctl or service command. The command as follows

```
systemctl start service_name or service service_name start
```

In that stop method am asking user to enter password which is not display on console(Suspecting ran in background). Stop method as follows

```
stop() {
read -s -p "Please provide password to stop the service" passwd
}
```

The same ran in CentOS 6 using service command, its displayed on console and entered the input. Can anyone please suggest me that am I missed something here to prompt or how we can prompt the user input using systemctl.

Comment: well from RHEL 6 to 7 a lot has changed such as upstart now being something else and such stuff like that. Most likely this has changed as well, you should go through the Centos changes from 6 to 7 to figure out what has changed and if it would cause an issue to what you are trying to do.

Comment: thats true jgr208, don't know what exactly the reason behind not prompting from RHEL 6 to 7. Thanks for comment.

Comment: CentOS 6 used upstart which was a more traditional service system in that it used shell scripts/etc. CentOS 7 uses systemd which doesn't (not for its core operation). It is quite likely that when it runs a "legacy" init script it does so in a detached/non-interactive fashion. That said prompting like that in the `stop` action seems very odd to me. Why would someone who doesn't have the authority/password for the service have the rights on that machine to stop it in the first place?

Comment: Good info Etan Reisner...thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, come to know that how to read password from user in CentOS 7. This is the command.

```
pwd=`systemd-ask-password --no-tty "Please enter admin password "`
```

systemd-ask-password — Query the user for a system password

Comment: Does this allow for interactive scripts to be run when using a systemctl call?